Get All Documents Inventory in a Site using PowerShell-
For each site, we need to extract one entry per item in the document library, including the item’s name, location, and size.
I have tried below script
#Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
#Function to Generate Report on all documents in a SharePoint Online Site Collection
Function Get-SPODocumentInventory($SiteURL)
{
Try {
#Setup the context
$Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
$Ctx.Credentials = $Credentials
#Get the web from given URL and its subsites
$Web = $Ctx.web
$Ctx.Load($Web)
$Ctx.Load($Web.Lists)
$Ctx.Load($web.Webs)
$Ctx.executeQuery()
#Arry to Skip System Lists and Libraries
$SystemLists =@("Converted Forms", "Master Page Gallery", "Customized Reports", "Form Templates", "List Template Gallery", "Theme Gallery",
"Reporting Templates", "Solution Gallery", "Style Library", "Web Part Gallery","Site Assets", "wfpub", "Site Pages", "Images")
Write-host -f Yellow "Processing Site: $SiteURL"
#Filter Document Libraries to Scan
$Lists = $Web.Lists | Where {$_.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary" -and $_.Hidden -eq $false -and $SystemLists -notcontains $_.Title -and $_.ItemCount -gt 0}
#Loop through each document library
Foreach ($List in $Lists)
{
#Define CAML Query to Get List Items in batches
$Query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery
$Query.ViewXml ="
<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>
<Query>
<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='TRUE'/></OrderBy>
</Query>
<RowLimit Paged='TRUE'>$BatchSize</RowLimit>
</View>"
Write-host -f Cyan "`t Processing Document Library: '$($List.Title)' with $($List.ItemCount) Item(s)"
Do {
#Get List items
$ListItems = $List.GetItems($Query)
$Ctx.Load($ListItems)
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
#Filter Files
$Files = $ListItems | Where { $_.FileSystemObjectType -eq "File"}
#Iterate through each file and get data
$DocumentInventory = @()
Foreach($Item in $Files)
{
$File = $Item.File
$Ctx.Load($File)
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
$DocumentData = New-Object PSObject
$DocumentData | Add-Member NoteProperty SiteURL($SiteURL)
$DocumentData | Add-Member NoteProperty DocLibraryName($List.Title)
$DocumentData | Add-Member NoteProperty FileName($File.Name)
$DocumentData | Add-Member NoteProperty FileURL($File.ServerRelativeUrl)
$DocumentData | Add-Member NoteProperty CreatedBy($Item["Author"].Email)
$DocumentData | Add-Member NoteProperty CreatedOn($File.TimeCreated)
$DocumentData | Add-Member NoteProperty ModifiedBy($Item["Editor"].Email)
$DocumentData | Add-Member NoteProperty LastModifiedOn($File.TimeLastModified)
$DocumentData | Add-Member NoteProperty Size-KB([math]::Round($File.Length/1KB))
#Add the result to an Array
$DocumentInventory += $DocumentData
}
#Export the result to CSV file
$DocumentInventory | Export-CSV $ReportOutput -NoTypeInformation -Append
$Query.ListItemCollectionPosition = $ListItems.ListItemCollectionPosition
} While($Query.ListItemCollectionPosition -ne $null)
}
#Iterate through each subsite of the current web and call the function recursively
ForEach ($Subweb in $Web.Webs)
{
#Call the function recursively to process all subsites underneaththe current web
Get-SPODocumentInventory($Subweb.url)
}
}
Catch {
write-host -f Red "Error Generating Document Inventory!" $_.Exception.Message
}
}
#Config Parameters
$SiteCollURL="https://crescent.sharepoint.com/sites/marketing"
$ReportOutput="C:\temp\DocInventory.csv"
$BatchSize = 500
#Setup Credentials to connect
$Cred= Get-Credential
$Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Cred.Username, $Cred.Password)
#Delete the Output Report, if exists
if (Test-Path $ReportOutput) { Remove-Item $ReportOutput }
#Call the function
Get-SPODocumentInventory $SiteCollURL
I have tried the above script , but i receive an error as -enter image description here . My account is MFA enabled .
How to enter  credentials with the traditional, login page experience.

You have a credentials error.  What is the $Credentials : $Ctx.Credentials = $Credentials  Are you running as an Admin?  You are trying to impersonate another user and need the permission to change user.

@jdweng - i referred this post - https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2018/03/sharepoint-online-get-all-documents-using-powershell.html

@iRon -For each site, we need to extract one entry per item in the document library, including the item’s name, location, and size. This is my requirement.

You have a credential issue. It could be many things.  It could be you are impersonating another user.  It could be the credentials are not recognized on the remote machine.  Most systems you need an encrypted credential to login into another machine, your code is note creating an encrypted credentials.  There are different types of credentials and the remote machine may not be configured correctly : Windows Credentials, OAUTH2 credentials.

Please, DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. and properly format your post, or even better add a [mcve] of what you trying to do. See also How do I ask a good question?
